# I want this jquery to give me position in % not in pixels

Tags: jquery-ui, responsive-design

**Here is what I have right now with me.This gives me absolute position in pixels**

```
$(this).css({
 "left" : ($(this).width() + 5) * (index % 4),
 "top" : ($(this).height() + 5) * Math.floor(index / 4)
});
```

I want this to give the positions in percentage relative to the screen size.

Please help.

Comment: I think you're using the % symbol wrong. in `C` like languages `%` is modulus not percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery will not return the value in %.

It will always return in px.

So, to get the value in %, you can divide the value with either the top most node [1st parent in dom]

```
 parseFloat($(this).width() / $('#idOfFirstParent').width()) * 100;
```

, if you want to get the value in reference to the 1st parent in the DOM or by width of the document [this will start with 0,0 of your screen].

```
 (parseFloat($(this).width() / $('window').width()) * 100).toFixed(2);

                             or 

 (parseFloat($(this).width() / $('document').width()) * 100).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple calculation using `$(window)`. For example to get the width of the item as a percentage of the `window`:

```
var percW = Math.floor(($(this).width / $(window).width()) * 100);
```