# getting width or height as percentage instead of pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have elements with an external style of `height` with percentages. when I am trying to save the height as a variable to use, it is saving it as `pixels`  some times nothing.

html
For example:

```
<div id='firstDiv'></div>
 <div id='secondDiv'></div>
```

css code

```
#firstDiv{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
#secondDiv{
   width:20%;
   height:50%;
}
```

Jquery code

```
$('div').each(function (){
   console.log($(this)[0].style.height);
}
```

how can i get it as `%`?

Comment: there is no way to get in percent but some trick height/100 would help ??

Comment: `$(this)[0]` can just be replaced by `this`, can't it?

Comment: and explain why do you need actually this in percentage ??? we could use an alternative for that....

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4006610/3153869
Hope, it will help

Comment: This is for width but you can use it for height as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235461/i-want-this-jquery-to-give-me-position-in-not-in-pixels/23235754#23235754

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get height in percentage instead of in pixels from inline style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235728/how-to-get-height-in-percentage-instead-of-in-pixels-from-inline-style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value in %, you can divide the value with either the top most node [1st parent in dom]

```
 parseFloat($(this)[0].style.height / $('#idOfFirstParent').height ()) * 100;
```

, if you want to get the value in reference to the 1st parent in the DOM or by width of the document [this will start with 0,0 of your screen].

```
 (parseFloat($(this)[0].style.height/ $('window').height ()) * 100).toFixed(2);

                         or 

 (parseFloat($(this)[0].style.height / $('document').height ()) * 100).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: are you sure `style.height` returns some value? sometimes it returns nothing (also the OP mentioned this), it does not return the computed style so we may have to use `getComputedStyle(element).height` or using `css` method of `jQuery`.

Comment: I used this bcoz Vikram did not state anything abt this, I simply used the script that he used to get the height. So i focussed on converting it into %.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, not direct option in jQuery.

```
var height = ( 100 * parseFloat($(element).css('height')) / parseFloat($(element).parent().css('height')) ) + '%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate the percentage:

```
var w = $("#myDiv").css("width").slice(0,-2);
var ww = $(window).width();
console.log(w/ww*100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parseInt(string).
It removes the chars after any numbers if the string begins with numbers

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).height()` will give height of your divs in percentage(as they have been set in percentage) and will be unit less.